# Find all the nodes that have at least 2 outgoing relations

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to learn neo4j on my own and I experience some difficulties. Let's say we have a graph and among the relations there are the relations `:DIRECTED` and `:ACTED_IN`.

Q. How can I return all the nodes that have **both** these relations as outgoing ones (I would appreciate an answer that is more general and can be extended to `k` fixed relations, instead of just `k=2` as in the example?)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) The first option (the nodes that have at least these [two relations](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/#_multiple_relationships)):

```
MATCH ()<-[:DIRECTED]-(I)-[:ACTED_IN]->()
RETURN distinct I
```

2) If you want to check the set of relationship types:

```
// Declare an array of type
WITH ['DIRECTED','ACTED_IN'] as rtypes
// Select connected nodes
MATCH (I)-[r]->()
WITH I, 
     rtypes,
     // Filter the types of relationships for this node on the basis of a given array types
     FILTER(rt in collect( distinct type(r) ) WHERE rt IN rtypes) as types
// The resulting array size must match the specified array
WHERE size(types) = size(rtypes)
RETURN I
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `size` operator and match on the returned number I think:

```
MATCH (a:Label) where size((a)--()) = 2
```

Note that you can also specify a direction for the relationship:

```
MATCH (a:Label) where size((a)-->()) = 2 //For outgoing relationships.
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer, but isn't this command going to return all the nodes that have at least **any** 3 types of relations?

Comment: Once again, shouldn't I declare somewhere in my code that I want these 2 specific relations to be satisfied?

Comment: Since your question is about matching "at least 2 relations" with "k" relations, I think this is enough. Else you can refer to stdob--'s answer which is more flexible and specifies the relationship type. My answer is better and faster if you just want nodes with at least X relationships.